# Home screen app like Lazy Swipe

Tags: android, homescreen

I have an app, where I need that some UI will appear on the screen whenever the user does some kind of pre-defined gesture. For example, top right to bottom left swipe will pop a dialog.
I don't really know where to start. What is the name for such tool? Where can I find more information about the subject?

Thanks in advance.